# php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] to include query string

Tags: php, redirect, authentication

I'm essentially trying to make a login system that will return the user back to the page they were on. I know this question has been asked a bit, and I've looked at the other answers on SO, but I cannot find a solution to my particular problem.

My site has has a table with reference id numbers (ex: 10001, 10003, 10004, ... 53401, etc.). These numbers are also links. All links point to one page ("mypage.php"), and the reference id number (10004) becomes a query string to that url:

```
<td><?php echo '<a href="mypage.php?query_ecr=', urlencode($num), '">'; ?><?php echo $num; ?></a></td>
```

On my "header.php", which is on every page of the site, there is a button on the menu that will open the form below for the user to log in.

```
<form action='login/process.php' method='post'>
  <label for='name'>Username:</label>
  <input type='text' id='userid' name='user_name'/>
  <label for='password'>Password:</label>
  <input type='password'  name='password' id='userpassword'/>

  <input type='submit' value='Log In' />

  <input type='hidden' name='login' value='1'>
  <input type='hidden' value='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' name='redirurl'/>
</form>
```

Notice the "hidden input" with the name='redirurl'. I want to capture the current page the user is on. I already have a login script that will check the username and password and redirect them to the page they need to be.

```
//login/process.php

...blah blah blah other stuff...

global $database,$session;
       $this->user_status=$database->CheckUserPass($_POST['user_name'],$_POST['password']);
       $url = $_POST['redirurl'];
       if($this->user_status==1)
          {
              $session->StartSession($_POST['user_name'],$_POST['password']);
              header("Location: ".$url);
        } else {
              ...blah blah blah.....
              }
```

My problem is that if the GUEST clicks on a link (ex: 10004), they are taken to the url:

```
http://www.XXXXXX.XXXX/mypage.php?query_ecr='10004'
```

However, on that page the value for 'redirurl' is:

```
http://www.XXXXXX.XXXX/mypage.php
```

It disregards the query string. So when the user logs in from that page, and my login script re-directs them back to that page, the page has a ton of errors because it needs the query string.

How do I include the query string in: $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

to get everything after the domain name folders, query strings etc.
You could then either use the other $_SERVER variables to add the domain, or it should be fine to use without a domain name provided you're not changing hosts.

Comment: Thank you to everyone else. You all have valid solutions, but this works the best because not all of my pages have query strings

Answer (score 7):

What about:

```
echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```

Note that you'll probably want to sanitize that output like so:

```
$url = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
echo htmlspecialchars($url, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');
```

to guard against XSS.

Answer (score 1):

The query string is available in `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`. Just concatenate them (don't forget the question mark) and you'll be fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

### Year: 2020

If any of you still looking for answer then here it is.

Let's say this is your web address:

```
www.example.com/foobar/foo/bar.php?id=23
```

Here's are the options. The first returns everthing after the domain and the second returns the current page and its query.

```
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
// /foobar/foo/har.php?id=23


echo pathinfo( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], PATHINFO_BASENAME ). '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
// bar.php?id=23
```