# Use a variable from another php file and recover it after an isset for a query

Tags: php, html, postgresql, forms

i'm trying to implement a Query that update a record on my psql database.
I need to select an ID, pass it to a form and then do a query

Manually inserting the ID it does work, and i cant get correctly my variable from the previous file, but when i submit the form it get lost and can't be used for the query

```
<?php
require("../common/top.php");
?>

<html>
<body>

<form method = "post" action = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
<select name="t_edit">
<option value = "" disabled selected > Aggiorna Stato </option>
<option value = "Aperto"> Aperto </option>
<option value = "In Corso"> In Corso </option>
<option value = "Chiuso"> Chiuso </option>
</select>
<input type = "submit" value = "Aggiorna">

</form>
</body>

<?php  
$t_id = (int)$_GET['id'];
echo "Status Ticket Numero: $t_id";

if (isset($_POST['t_edit'])) 
{
$selected = $_POST['t_edit'];
global $conn;
$new_status = pg_query($conn,"UPDATE tickets SET status = '$selected'      WHERE id='" . $t_id . "'");
} 
?>
```

I have a list of Plants:
ex Plant 1
   Plant 2
   Plant 3 
   ...
I select it from a previous page, directly from the same database

```
$result = pg_query($conn, "SELECT id,t_user,plant,status,type,details,date_added FROM tickets WHERE plant='$plant'");
```

then I pass the 'id' to the next php page

```
<td> <a href='t_test3.php?id=". $row['id']. "' ' >Edit</a> </td>
```

I need to use that very same 'id' to make the new query

But when i click Submit on the last php file it get lost and return id=0

Comment: PHP_SELF does not include the query string. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20127113/php-serverphp-self-to-include-query-string

Comment: 1) you're open to SQL injection and should address imminently. 2) using globals inside a function is usually never the answer, use parameters instead.

Comment: You're right, I'll rearrange with function already declared without passing globals or re-declare whole functions. I'm just trying to make it work 'manually' and then refine it. It's just a piece of formation so learning focused. Thanks for the comment!